# What's the result of this integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, integration, mathematics, calculus

$$\int_{|\vec k|<k_F} \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r} $$
it's not a Fourier transformation since the integrand is not infinite.

Comment: For the record, it *is* a Fourier transform (of a step function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\int_{-k_F}^{k_F}\frac{k^2dk}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{-\pi}^\pi d\phi\int_{-1}^1d\cos(\theta) e^{ikr\cos\theta}
$$
Could you go on from here?

Comment: thanks, is the result $\frac {\sin {kr}}{\pi^2r^3}$?

Comment: @Shuo It should depend on $k_F$, but $k$. I got a slightly different result, but the crucial question is whether the $k_F\to\infty$ limit is sensible.